# Why it is an error to convert a base class for curious template pattern to another base class directly?

Tags: c++, crtp

I am learning curious template pattern(crpt pattern).
I would like to reduce a duplicated code in a class with crtp pattern.
The points of the following example are

1. class C is a maintainer of containers, class Container<(int)> and Container<(double)>
2. class C provides a way to access the containers above.
3. The function to access the containers is implemented with crtp pattern as GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP<(C)>.

The following code works well. But it does not work if I change
code from case 2 to case 1 in GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP::container_pair(); for me, codes of case 1 and case 2 are equivalent.

Why does code of case 1 fail to convert base class for crtp to another base class?
And, I would like to clear whether code of case 2 is valid in c++ regulation which provides a way to access to another base class.

Thank you very much.

Code :

```
template <typename T>
class Container : public std::vector<T> {};

template <typename Derived>
class GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP {
public:

    template <typename T>
    auto& container_pair(void) {

        // case 1: error at compiling
        // return static_cast<typename Derived::template ContianerChoice<T>&>(*this);

        // case 2: works well
        Derived* host = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        return static_cast<typename Derived::template ContianerChoice<T>&>(*host);
    }
};

class C : private Container<int>, private Container<double>, public GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP<C> {
public:

    template <typename T>
    using ContianerChoice = Container<T>;

    C(void) {
        this->Container<int>::push_back(1);
        this->Container<double>::push_back(3);
    }

    friend class GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP<C>;

};


void test_get_container_by_crtp(void) {

    C c{};

    auto& container_int = c.container_pair<int>();
    std::cout << "value of contianer int at index 0 = " << container_int[0] << "." << std::endl;

    auto& container_double = c.container_pair<double>();
    std::cout << "value of contianer double at index 0 = " << container_double[0] << "." << std::endl;

}
```

Result of execution test_get_container_by_crtp() above :

```
value of contianer int at index 0 = 1.
value of contianer double at index 0 = 3.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distil your problem down, you are essentially asking why the following doesn't work:

```
struct base_a {};
struct base_b {};
struct derived : base_a, base_b {};

derived d;
base_a& a = d;
base_b& b = static_cast<base_b&>(a); // error: cannot cast from `base_a&` to `base_b&`
```

To quote [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), given an expression `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`:

> If `new_type` is a pointer or reference to some class `D` and the type of `expression` is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base `B`, `static_cast` performs a *downcast*.

You are trying to do the equivalent of `static_cast<base_b&>(a)`, and since `base_a` is not a non-virtual base class of `base_b`, this is not a valid downcast. You instead need to downcast to `derived&` which then implicitly converts to `base_b&`:

```
base_b& b = static_cast<derived&>(a);
```

Or in your case:

```
template <typename T>
auto& container_pair(void) {
    using Choice = typename Derived::template ContianerChoice<T>;
    Choice& c = static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does code of case 1 fail to convert base class for crtp to another base class?

That's how `static_cast` works. `Container<To>` is neither a derived class nor a base class of `GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP<C>`, so you cannot use `static_cast` to cast between them.
Anyway, it happens that `Container<To>` is a base class of `C`, so you can use `static_cast` to cast `GET_CONTAINRE_CRTP<C>` to its derived class `C` and **then** cast it to the desired container (that is another subclass).
Otherwise, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to do the work at once.